# Some primary keys are missing in the SQL Server table. Why is that so?? is the any transaction which is not ended or something else?

Tags: sql-server, database, primary-key

There is data saving part in my work. While doing it data has saved in the table, but as my concern primary key should be last primary + 1, but some primary keys are not there. Why is that so??

My my table has primary keys 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12
In this primary key 11 is missing.

Comment: it might be deleted record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a record, in your case 11 is deleted and another record is added to the table it is added as 12 and not 11.

Comment: How do i change the IDs of a whole table to be in order ? like to make the 12 -> 11 so that there is no missing numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Identity and Sequence column don't  guaranty end-to-end numbering +1